# В какой момент segue срабатывает?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

В целом как пользоваться `segue` понятно, не совсем понятно так сказать детали)

Вот к примеру есть такой кусок кода

---

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == StoryBoard.ShowImageSegue {
        if let ivc = segue.destination.contentViewController as? ImageViewController {
            let imageName = (sender as? UIButton)?.currentTitle
            ivc.imageURL = DemoUrl.NASAImageNamed(imageName: imageName)
            ivc.title = imageName
        }
    }
}
```

---

Есть `split view` в нем кнопки, нажимаю на кнопку открывается следующей `view controller`.

Так вот в какой момент в этой функции срабатывает этот `segue`?

Вот в андроиде допустим понятно `start Activity()` и как эта строчка кода будет выполнена полетит запрос на открытие нужного активити...

А в iOS такой строчки нет и не понятно в какой момент летит этот запрос на открытие нужного экрана

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой не срабатывает, здесь подготовка к переходу.

`segue` это переход. Переход с одного контроллера на другой.

Последовательность вызовов методов `seque`:

- `initWithIdentifier:source:destination:` (инициализация)
- `prepareForSegue:sender:` (подготовка, для нас наиболее "популярный" метод)
- `perform` (вот здесь срабатывает)

Ну а насчет когда срабатывает - когда выполнились условия, тогда и срабатывает. Нажали на кнопку, подготвилось и сработало.

Если же сравнивать с андроидом, то там и близко нет такого. Аналог `startActivity()` будет `present(:animated:completion:)`

Comment: Значит если я правильно понял, то переход включает 3 метода мы переопределяем только один `prepareForSegue:sender:` , но сама отработка перехода происходит в `perform` , но мы его не переопределяем, так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko из основного да. В "жизненном цикле" segue в самом начале есть еще инициализация контроллера на который должен осуществиться переход и деинициализация seque в конце.

Comment: Сперва `perform` срабатывает который инициализирует `segue` , а потом уже `prepare:`. Документация `performSegue:`: `Initiates the segue with the specified identifier from the current view controller's storyboard file.`, это когда `segue` вручную вызывается. А если `segue` в `storyboard` на какой то `event` приписан, то там немножко по другому все происходит.

Comment: @FahriAzimov не путайте `perform` класса `UIStoryboardSegue`, который выполняет переход и `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`  класса `UIViewController`. А жизненный цикл одинаков у `segue`, что в коде через `performSegue` выполните, что в интерфейс билдере на кнопку какую повесите.